# image's table creates differend foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql

I  have a code which inserts into more 3 tables . what happens is that  if I create a new account at the same time I upload images for that account in the images table . The code does it very well but now the problem is it gives each image a unique referenced user_Id yet  all images uploaded  for that user should be with the same Id from the user table .I am using a relational database where by the user table has a primary key  user_id which is referenced to other tables as their foreign key . bellow is my code : ant help will be appreciated .

```
<?php
#connect to the db
require_once('db.inc.php');
?>
<?php
#code to deal with the picture uploads 
#target folder 
$target = 'image_uploads/';
  if(isset($_FILES['image_name'])===true){
  $files = $_FILES['image_name'];
  for($x = 0 ; $x < count($files['name']); $x++){
  $name = $files['name'][$x] ;
  $temp_name = $files['tmp_name'][$x];
  #extention filter it takes only the extension  want 
$allowed ='gif,png,jpg,pdf';
$extension_allowed= explode(',',$allowed );  
$file_extention = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(array_search($file_extention,$extension_allowed)){
}else {
echo 'We only allow gif, png ,jpg';
  exit();
} #extention  filter ends here 
  #check the size of the image 
  $file_size = $files['size'][$x];
  if($file_size > 2097152){
  echo 'The file should be lesS than 2MB';
  exit();
  }
    #check the size of the image  ends here
  #Rename images 
  $sub = substr(md5(rand()),0,7);
  #the above generates char and numbesr 
  $rand = rand(0,100000);
  $rename = $rand.$sub.$name;
  #Rename images ends here
  $move = move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$target.$rename); 

#code to deal with the picture uploads ends here 
?>
<?php 
$date_created= date('y-m-d h:i:s a');
$username=(isset($_POST['username']))? trim($_POST['username']): '';
$Previllage =(isset($_POST['Previllage']))? trim($_POST['Previllage']): '';
#second tanble values 
$title=(isset($_POST['title']))? trim($_POST['title']): '';
$firstname=(isset($_POST['firstname']))? trim($_POST['firstname']): '';
$lastname=(isset($_POST['lastname']))? trim($_POST['lastname']): '';
$client_code=(isset($_POST['client_code']))? trim($_POST['client_code']): '';
$job_approval=(isset($_POST['job_approval']))? trim($_POST['job_approval']): '';
$address=(isset($_POST['address']))? trim($_POST['address']): '';
$cell=(isset($_POST['cell']))? trim($_POST['cell']): '';
$tel=(isset($_POST['tel']))? trim($_POST['tel']): '';
$email=(isset($_POST['email']))? trim($_POST['email']): '';
$company=(isset($_POST['company']))? trim($_POST['company']): '';
$province=(isset($_POST['province']))? trim($_POST['province']): '';
$username= substr(md5(rand()),0,7);
$Pas=substr(md5(rand()),0,4);
$Password =(md5($Pas));
$user =(isset($_POST['$user']))? trim($_POST['$user']): '';
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
try{
$query="INSERT INTO tish_user(username,Password,Previllage,date_created)
VALUES(:username,:Password,:Previllage,:date_created)";
$insert = $con->prepare($query);
$insert->execute(array(
':username'=>$username,
':Password'=>$Password,
':Previllage'=>$Previllage,
':date_created'=>$date_created));
#end of first table
################################################
#You select the first Id and put it in a variable then 
$id_last = ("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$result =$con->prepare($id_last);
$result->execute();
$last_id = $result->fetchColumn();
############################## Last Id query Ends here
#insert into  clientinfo table 
$clientinfor="INSERT INTO tish_clientinfo(title,firstname,lastname,user_id)
VALUES(:title,:firstname,:lastname,$last_id)";
$clientinfor_insert = $con->prepare($clientinfor);
$clientinfor_insert->execute(array(
':title'=>$title,
':firstname'=>$firstname,
':lastname'=>$lastname));
#end of clien infor 
################################################
$security="INSERT INTO tish_security(ip_address,user_id)
VALUES(:ip_address,$last_id)";
$security_insert = $con->prepare($security);
$security_insert->execute(array(
':ip_address'=>$ip_address));
##########################end of security 
############ images 
$images ="INSERT INTO tish_images(user_id,image_name,date_registered)
VALUES($last_id,:image_name,:date_registered)";
$images_insert = $con->prepare($images);
$images_insert->execute(array(
':image_name'=>$rename,
':date_registered'=>$date_created));
############# property table##########################################################
/*$property ="INSERT INTO tish_propertyinfo(user_id,date_registered)
VALUES($last_id,:date_registered)";
$property_insert = $con->prepare($images);
$property_insert->execute(array(':date_registered'=>$date_created));
*/}catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}

  } 
}
?>
```

Comment: Is the user_id in the image table unique key? Do  you use this code for every image upload by a particular user?

Comment: for database check http://pastebin.com/7ZJhxzyi

Comment: And the other question?

Comment: good question: Creates your code for every image upload a new user? As @user2008945 asked :)

Comment: @Fabian what iam trying to do is that I create a user and I load many images but in the images table only 1 picture grabs the user_id from the user's table . this means tht the last_id is not null . so how can I make other images get the same ID

Comment: Ok, so you have a form (simplified) with a username and an image upload field. What you want is to load up an image, and do the same again and have no new user created? then you need to split the two things. Put the user_id id a hidden field or if you have the id in the session use the id from there. As long as you create a new user while uploading images, you have this problem

Comment: ok I guess I should use sessions

Comment: it loads images aas many a I want but it creates a different forien key 4 each iamge and it gives 1 image the orignal foreign key from the user table

Answer (score 0):

Is there a auto increment on user_id in the image table? And checknwether $last_id contains anything, I would thinkni is NULL.

Comment: in the images table there is no auto_increment . for thr  last Id how can I check if its null or not plse help

Comment: look what I got string(2) "11" string(2) "12" string(2) "13" string(2) "14"